# El array siempre está vacío y no coge los objetos - JSON

Tags: android, json, rest, android-asynctask

Estoy obteniendo datos usando servicios *Rest*, y tengo un problema con el *"get."*. Cuando obtengo el JSON en modo texto y lo muestro, aparece completamente y sin ningún problema por consola, pero al crear el array de JSON lo crea siempre vacío y nunca inserta ningún dato. He probado a coger un solo JSON y varios JSON de la URL, pero no funciona. ¿Alguna solución? La aplicación, no lanza ningún mensaje de error, pero siempre está nulo.

```
public class FeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>{

private OnFeedListener listener;

public FeedTask(OnFeedListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
    String url=params[0];
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    Request.Builder builder=new Request.Builder();
    Request request=builder.url(url).build();
    try {
        Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();
        String json=response.body().string();
       try{
            //JSONArray jsona=new JSONArray(json);
            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(json);
            //JSONObject object=jsona.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray array= object.optJSONArray("posts");
            return array;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray array) {
    super.onPostExecute(array);
    if(array==null){
        System.out.println("\n--------------------"+"es nulo"+"-----\n");
        return;
    }
    if(listener!=null){
        System.out.println("\n--------------------"+"carga datos"+"-----\n");
        listener.onFeed(array);
    }
}}
```

Comment: puedes dejar el formato del json que recibes??

Comment: Sí, te dejo un trozo. Es el que devuelve wordpress con RestAPI "id":1747,"date":"2016-11-15T14:33:03","date_gmt":"2016-11-15T12:33:03","guid":{"rendered":"XXXXXXX"},"modified":"2016-11-15T14:33:03","modified_gmt":"2016-11-15T12:33:03","slug":"XXXXXX","type":"post","link":"XXXXXX","title":{"rendered":"XXXXXXX"},"content":{"rendered":XXX" .....

Comment: en el bloque que dejaste no veo por ningun lado el array posts

Comment: Que es lo que necesitas exactamente? Lo que te he adjuntado es parte del JSON que devuelve la URL. Después filtro los datos que recibo para utilizar solo aquellos que necesito. En el código de arriba, cuando creo el JSON me lo coge bien con los datos que recibe pero al insertar ese JSON en el JSONArray no lo mete es ahí donde está el problema no en el JSONObject :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto siempre te va a ocurrir porque el json que devuelve la api NO contiene el array `posts`

Ejemplo :

```
[{
    "ID": 2328,
    "content": "<p>Everything we do communicates.</p>\n",
    /* ...snip most of the fields... */
    "title": "Pete Episcopo",
    "type": "post"
}, {
    "ID": 2326,
    "content": "<p>The only &#8220;intuitive&#8221; interface is the nipple. After that it&#8217;s all learned.</p>\n",
    /* ...snip most of the fields... */
    "title": "Bruce Ediger",
    "type": "post"
}, {
    "ID": 2323,
    "content": "<p>Only show work you like, or you&#8217;ll end up being hired to do things you don&#8217;t like.</p>\n",
    /* ...snip most of the fields... */
    "title": "Victoria Pater",
    "type": "post"
}]
```

Para consumir este arreglo debes simplemente :

```
String json = response.body().string();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
return jsonArray;

//Para leer los objetos si quieres
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){                        
   JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);     
}
```

Al estar ejecutando `JSONArray array= object.optJSONArray("posts");` esta funcion trae un arreglo que tiene que tener este formato

```
{
    "posts": [{
        "ID": 2328,
        "content": "<p>Everything we do communicates.</p>\n",
        /* ...snip most of the fields... */
        "title": "Pete Episcopo",
        "type": "post"
    }, {
        "ID": 2326,
        "content": "<p>The only &#8220;intuitive&#8221; interface is the nipple. After that it&#8217;s all learned.</p>\n",
        /* ...snip most of the fields... */
        "title": "Bruce Ediger",
        "type": "post"
    }, {
        "ID": 2323,
        "content": "<p>Only show work you like, or you&#8217;ll end up being hired to do things you don&#8217;t like.</p>\n",
        /* ...snip most of the fields... */
        "title": "Victoria Pater",
        "type": "post"
    }]
}
```

Pero como el arreglo que devuelve la api no tiene index (nombre) ya es una `array` por lo tanto no tienes que buscar un `array` ya que por como viene ya lo es.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Todo solucionado :) Llevaba atracando varias horas en ese punto.

Comment: Saludos @Francisco exito con eso!